# Substitution in %x command in Ruby

Tags: ruby, command, substitution

I am writing a Ruby script to unzip a file where each pass through the `%x{unzip }` will have a different file name.

I have been successful getting

`%x{unzip FILENAME.ZIP}` to unzip the contents of FILENAME.ZIP

However, I want to be able to pass in the name of the file to unzip.

I've tried variations of

```
filename = "CONSTANT+variable+"NEXT_CONSTANT.ZIP"
%x{${filename}}
```

and I have been unable to get the `%x` to let me construct a filename that I want to unzip.

Comment: `%x{${filename}}`  The thing about programming is that you can't just make up the syntax as you go along.  `${filename}` is not part of the ruby programming language.

Comment: Can you rephrase this as a question?  It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the same way you'd do it in a double-quoted string: `#{filename}`.

```
filename = "my_files.zip"
%x{unzip #{filename}}
```

Comment: Whooo-hooo, thank you - that did the trick (now to go off and understand it ;) )